# Can a question begin with the word "must"?

Tags: modal-verbs, questions

Let's take the affirmative sentence: Peter must go there.
Can I ask such a question: "Must Peter go there?"
Or only "Does Peter have to go there?" is correct?

Comment: I am glad to hear that I can start the question with "must". My grammar test says it is wrong. Perhaps the test is not perfect itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can begin an interrogative sentence with a modal verb,

> Must I do this?
> May I do this?
> Can I do this?
> Should I do this?
> Would I do this?

http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/modal.htm

Comment: I'm very glad indeed to read that "must I do this ?" is correct ! All my teachers have always told me it was wrong, obliging me to write "do I have to do it ?" is it recent form ? Was it considered as wrong 20 years ago ?

Comment: This may be a difference between US and UK usage.  "Must I ___?" sounds a little stilted to this US English speaker, but I feel like I've seen it in UK usage.  Hopefully a UK native speaker can address this.

Comment: AmE speakers do use utterances such as: "Must you do that? It is really getting on my nerves." Of course, this is not trailer park speech.